# Merging 2 datatables but adding a column

Tags: .net, datatable

I have 2 datatable, say dt1, dt2. Both have same columns, say C1, C2, C3, C4 and C5. C5 is numeric column. I want to merge both datatable but at the same time I want to add C5 while merging where C1, C2, C3 and C4 are same. Can anyone pls suggest

Comment: Add C5 based on what condition?

Comment: Just dt1.C5 + dt2.C5, where dt1.C1 = dt2.C1 and dt1.C2 = dt2.C2 and dt1.C3 = dt2.C3 and dt1.C4 = dt2.C4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the second datatable rows and compare it with each row in first datatable.If the first 4 column values match then sum the 5th column value else add the row to the first datatable.

```
foreach (DataRow r2 in dt2.Rows)
{
    bool rowExists = false;
    foreach (DataRow r1 in dt1.Rows)
    {
        if((r1["C1"] == r2["C1"])&&(r1["C2"] == r2["C2"])&&(r1["C3"] == r2["C3"])&&(r1["C4"] == r2["C4"]))
        {
            r1["C5"] = r1["C5"] + r2["C5"];
            rowExists = true;
            break;
        }                          
    }
    if(!rowExists)
        dt1.Rows.Add(r2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do we have to call "acceptchanges" somewhere?

Comment: yes it works. I read somewhere that datatable needs "dt.acceptchanges" to commit, however this one works perfect!

Comment: gives an error on line "dt1.Rows.Add(r2);". says "This row already belonds to another table"